# What have I to index onto this db?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a query that make some joins.

```
SELECT feedback.note as notes, 
to_char(feedback.data_compilazione,'DD/MM/YYYY') as date, 
CAST(feedback.punteggio AS INT) as score, 
upper(substring(cliente.nome from '^.') || '.' || 
substring(cliente.cognome from '^.') || '.') as customer, 
testo.testo as nation FROM feedback 
JOIN prenotazione ON prenotazione.id = feedback.id_prenotazione 
JOIN cliente ON cliente.id = prenotazione.id_cliente 
JOIN struttura ON struttura.id = prenotazione.id_struttura 
JOIN lingua ON cliente.id_lingua = lingua.id 
JOIN nazione ON cliente.codice_nazione = nazione.codice_iso 
JOIN testo ON testo.nome_tabella = 'nazione' AND testo.id_record = nazione.id AND
testo.id_lingua = lingua.id AND testo.id_tipo_testo = 1 WHERE struttura.id = 43 AND
lingua.sigla = E'en' AND feedback.punteggio >= 3 AND feedback.note <> '' 
ORDER BY feedback.data_compilazione DESC LIMIT 5
```

My problem is that I haven't any explicit index onto my tables.

This means that this query took a long,long,long....long time to be executed.

AFAIK postresql creates an "implicit" index every time a declare a primary key, so I haven't to add it "explicitly".

This is the `EXPLAIN` of the query

```
"Limit  (cost=212.72..212.73 rows=1 width=208)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=212.72..212.73 rows=1 width=208)"
"        Sort Key: feedback.data_compilazione"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.11..212.71 rows=1 width=208)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.11..206.86 rows=1 width=212)"
"                    Join Filter: (("outer".codice_nazione)::text = ("inner".codice_iso)::text)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.11..201.63 rows=1 width=223)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.11..195.60 rows=1 width=187)"
"                                Join Filter: ("outer".id = "inner".id_cliente)"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.11..45.18 rows=1 width=183)"
"                                      Join Filter: ("outer".id_lingua =    "inner".id_lingua)"
"                                      ->  Index Scan using testo_pkey on testo  (cost=0.00..6.27 rows=1 width=40)"
"                                            Index Cond: (((nome_tabella)::text = 'nazione'::text) AND (id_tipo_testo = 1))"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.11..38.86 rows=4 width=155)"
"                                            Hash Cond: ("outer".id_lingua = "inner".id)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on cliente  (cost=0.00..33.47 rows=847 width=151)"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=1.11..1.11 rows=1 width=4)"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on lingua  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=1 width=4)"
"                                                        Filter: ((sigla)::text = 'en'::text)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on prenotazione  (cost=0.00..150.05 rows=30 width=12)"
"                                      Filter: (43 = id_struttura)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using feedback_id_prenotazione_key on feedback  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=44)"
"                                Index Cond: ("outer".id = feedback.id_prenotazione)"
"                                Filter: ((punteggio >= 3::double precision) AND (note <> ''::text))"
"                    ->  Index Scan using nazione_pkey on nazione  (cost=0.00..5.21 rows=1 width=11)"
"                          Index Cond: ("outer".id_record = nazione.id)"
"              ->  Index Scan using struttura_pkey on struttura  (cost=0.00..5.82 rows=1 width=4)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = 43)"
```

So I stopped to think about indexing on DB.
What is the best practise for creating index? 
The solution is: **create an index for every joined field?**

And into my DB, what you suggest to index?

I've done some try (substantially index every field that is joined) and the query run now faster but not fast (about six second to retrive zero rows). 
I suppose that mine solution isn't the best.

Anybody can point my look at the right direction?

**EDIT**

If I add just an index (on prenotazione.id_cliente) all works in very few seconds (1,5 about). So, why add all indexes on FOREIGN keys make my query run slower?

Comment: It looks like the tables are already at least partially indexed. A few other considerations are the string contatenation and there are a few sequence scans (instead of index scans) in there, and finally, ensure your indexing strategy is sound (look for Postgresql index types).

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE ? That also shows us the time for every step, the most important factor in your question.

Comment: @FrankHeikens : now I've add an index and that's works, so have I to remove index and do E.A. ? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first rule of thumb, without even looking at the query plan, I would certainly put indexes on foreign keys that have a high (>100 distinct values) selectivity.

Some databases put them without asking, Postgres doesn't.
We are talking about indexes on FOREIGN keys, not PRIMARY ones (these are obviously always provided).

For instance, `prenotazione.id_struttura`, and `feedback.id_prenotazione` are likely candidates.

On the other hand, a `weekday` column of 7 distinct values would not benefit from an index, unless there are thousands of mondays and very few sundays, in which case the index is selective for some values.

Comment: If I add just an index (on prenotazione.id_cliente) all works in very few seconds (1,5 about). So, why add all indexes on FOREIGN keys make my query run slower?

Comment: BTW your answer is nice, and if no one will answer better than you, i'll accept this. But i'm curious about the previous comment that i gave you. Have you any idea? Just for understand the whole process and aplly again in future

Comment: A possible cause: if the values are few and uniformly spread, each data page will likely contain all of the values at once, so accessing by indexes requires more indirection, more seeking and ultimately retrieves the same data. A table scan can be faster, depending on table size and a bunch of other stuff. non-SSD hard disks are a hundred times faster during sequential access. Whether postgres decides to use an index or not, depends on statistics etc. etc. I suggest giving a look at "Refactoring SQL applications", by O'Reilly, not too hard, but effective and enlightening.

Comment: This is the same explaination that I gave to me. Thank you very much!